# Is there a way to center a text vertically regardless of font-family or font-size?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, webfonts

I am looking for a font-agnostic way of centering text in a div. I have a button style fixed height div. And i want to center the text in it (one line only) vertically. The problem is that when i change the font-family, some fonts do not center vertically. Is there a way to compute the desired lineheight based on font metrics?

Comment: can you elaborate with an example ?

Comment: Please show what you currently have, so people don't need to waste their time to post answers you've already tried.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution, hope it works for you.

```css
.content{
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <span>Hello world</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `line-height` equal to the height of the button.

```css
div {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>Button</div>
```

Comment: That wont work with all fonts. Some fonts are built differently and the do not center.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, im not using line height:

```css
button {
  height: 40px;
  display: table;
}

button>span {
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

button.one {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-size: 30px;
}

button.two {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

button.three {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 18px; 
}

button.four {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
}

button.five {
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<button class="one"><span>text</span></button>
<br>
<br>
<button class="two"><span>text</span></button>
<br>
<br>
<button class="three"><span>text</span></button>
<br>
<br>
<button class="four"><span>text</span></button>
<br>
<br>
<button class="five"><span>text</span></button>
```

If the text `size` extends the height of the button then you wil get a failed result which should be obvios, since the button has a `fixed` height.